# Logo for my iPhone application

Tags: iphone

I would to ask please what software to use to conceive the logo of my iPhone app and if the logo should respect some standards given by Apple?

Comment: If my answer meets your requirements, you should mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use any photo-generation/editing program, so long as you follow Apple's [guidelines.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html)